# FieldInfo.GetValue() can crash your program; how does one avoid this?

Tags: c#, reflection, crash, mono

It appears that certain calls to `FieldInfo.GetValue()` can outright crash your program with some versions of Mono/.NET (or at least the Mono version packaged with Unity).

Specifically, when given an instance of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`, attempting to evaluate the field `"Systen.Int32* calendar_data"` using `FieldInfo.GetValue()` will cause the process to crash. This is the stack trace:

```
0x00007FFC0A6A3C58 (KERNELBASE) RaiseException
0x00007FFBDCFD1158 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono\build\eglib\src\goutput.c:201] g_logv 
0x00007FFBDCFD117C (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono\build\eglib\src\goutput.c:211] g_log 
0x00007FFBDD04E223 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono\build\mono\metadata\object.c:2945] mono_field_get_value_object 
0x000000001179273B (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoField:GetValueInternal (object)
0x00000000117924D6 (Mono JIT Code) [/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoField.cs:118] System.Reflection.MonoField:GetValue (object)
```

Also, a call to `FieldInfo.GetValue` on an instance of `Mono.Globalization.Unicode.SimpleCollator` caused a similar crash, although the exact evaluated member could not be determined.

**I'm trying to figure out if there is a pattern to crashes caused by `FieldInfo.GetValue` calls**, I.E. what calls will crash the program and which ones won't.

Any namespace named `Globalization` seems to contain classes prone to making reflection crashy, but I doubt that's the cause.

Does`FieldInfo.GetValue()` try to return the object pointed to by a pointer? This would be pretty bizarre as you'd expect it to return a memory address (e.g. `IntPtr`) given that it is a pointer type, otherwise it'd be impossible to null check the pointer. Nonetheless I can skip pointer fields if it prevents a crash.

Comment: Can you provide a little compilable example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I tried reproducing this in `https://dotnetfiddle.net/`, but it appears that it structures the fields of the `CultureInfo` objects very differently in that it doesn't use pointers. Perhaps the instability of using reflection with pointers is a more widespread problem that isn't limited to our particular version of Mono.

Comment: Did you find out anything else about this issue?